mariadb requires mysql:root to start instead of mysql:mysql for user:group - RHEL 8.9 mariadb 10.5.23
After patching and reboot for mariadb to start we require to do the following cmd to launch mariadb
chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql
otherwise we get the following error
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.23 started; log sequence number 114858617868828; transaction id 6884951201
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /data/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
May 21 00:43:07 sprcellapp mariadbd[104253]: 2024-05-21  0:43:07 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 21 00:43:08 sprcellapp systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 21 00:43:08 sprcellapp systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 21 00:43:08 sprcellapp systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.23 database server.

SELinux is in permissive mode and we saw no avc:denied in syslog messages
finally /var/lib/mysql had the ownership and permissions:
"drwxr-xr-x. 5 mysql mysql 231 May 21 00:51 /var/lib/mysql/"
and after change for mariadb to launch would be need to be this.
drwxr-xr-x.  5 mysql root        231 May 21 00:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 64 root  root       4096 Feb  3 16:51 ..
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root      24576 Feb  4 11:17 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root         52 Feb  4 11:17 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root        976 Feb  4 11:17 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root   12582912 Feb  4 11:17 ibdata1
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root  100663296 Feb  4 11:17 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql root          0 Jan 31 14:51 multi-master.info
drwx------.  2 mysql root       4096 Jan 31 14:25 mysql
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql mysql         0 May 21 00:51 mysql.sock
-rw-r--r--.  1 mysql root         15 Jan 31 14:25 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------.  2 mysql root         20 Jan 31 14:25 performance_schema
drwx------.  2 mysql root         20 Jan 31 14:25 test

Note the mysql.sock file created as mysql:mysql after mariadb launches.
Why is the directory group owner required to be root?

"after patching" - patching what?  did you upgrade mariadb?

it was normal security and monthly patching. mariadb was NOT upgraded. This is a new server and I am not sure that after the next patch/reboot if the /var/lib/mysql somehow goes back to mysql:mysql. Will know this after the next patch/reboot. If it does go back then we would have the same issue. If not then problem solved. Unfortunately we can not reboot until next patch in a few weeks. But the question is normally that directory should be mysql:mysql on the older system and it work like that on other installations except for this new server.

So we found the issue. The problem was that the mysql user (from LDAP) was already defined and had a UID of 260, however when the mysql was installed on this new machine it generated a new UID and GID which did not match the /etc/passwd and etc/group of 269 and 979 respectively. This is why changing the permissions to mysql:root of /var/lib/mysql solved the problem but you had to do that on every reboot since /var/lib/mysql would revert back to mysql:mysql. So to fix this we simply changed the UID and GID to 260/260 which matched the ldap user. Now after reboot nothing needs to be changed.
process was

shut MariaDB off

sudo systemctl stop mariadb

check if any process is running for 260 which is mysql
ps -ef | grep mysql
ps -ef | grep 260

if none OK if not stop

backup the /etc files
sudo cp -p /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bkp
sudo cp -p /etc/group /etc/group.bkp

verify the id first
id mysql

change groupid first


sudo groupmod -g 260 mysql

change the userid

sudo usermod -u 260 -g 260 mysql
note if returns nothing to update then edit the /etc/passwd file manually since it could be using the LDAP and still set to 269 in our example, so update to 260

verify changes
id mysql

optional
8a. sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
8b. sudo systemctl start mariadb
this will test to make sure after reboot the maraidb boots.
==

reboot the server

now after reboot /var/lib/mysql is mysql:mysql and the socket files is able to be placed in this DIR
check /var/log/messages for errors
